# Geoserver: Problem with default styles

Tags: geoserver, java

Somehow, many of the layers in **Geoserver got misconfigured**. I can not say how this exactly happend, since this also applies to layers I have not even touched in a while.

When I try to query the layers (counts for a lot of layers i have in my geosever configuration) via REST, like so: `www.mygeoserverhome.com/geoserver/rest/layers/Filialgebiete_UM1.html`, i get back the following error message:

> Layer "Filialgebiete_UM1" Name: Filialgebiete_UM1 Default style:
> Expression properties.defaultStyle is undefined on line 6, column 24
> in LayerInfo.ftl. The problematic instruction: ---------- ==>
> ${properties.defaultStyle} [on line 6, column 22 in LayerInfo.ftl]
> ---------- Java backtrace for programmers: ---------- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression
> properties.defaultStyle is undefined on line 6, column 24 in
> LayerInfo.ftl. at
> freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
> at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118) at
> freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93) at
> freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76) at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221) at
> freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92) at
> freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221) at
> freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199) at
> freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237) at
> org.restlet.ext.freemarker.TemplateRepresentation.write(TemplateRepresentation.java:112)
> at
> com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.writeResponseBody(HttpServerCall.java:342)
> at
> com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.sendResponse(HttpServerCall.java:306)
> at
> com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletCall.sendResponse(ServletCall.java:306)
> at
> org.geoserver.rest.GeoServerServletConverter.commit(GeoServerServletConverter.java:54)
> at
> com.noelios.restlet.ext.servlet.ServletConverter.service(ServletConverter.java:130)
> at
> org.geoserver.rest.RESTDispatcher.handleRequestInternal(RESTDispatcher.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
> at
> org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
> at
> org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
> at
> org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
> at
> org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
> at
> org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:83)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
> at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324) at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
> at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
> at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514) at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211) at
> org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380) at
> org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
> at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run
>
> (BoundedThreadPool.java:450)

What could possibly be going wrong here?

Is there a chance to resolvethis issue somehow, or should I delete all the layers, reupload and and hope for this to not happen again?

Geoserver 2.7.2 on a windows machine.